# Como conocer la duración de un elemento audio HTML cuyo source es un string Base64?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Me explico, deseo calcular la duración de un segmento de audio base64 a partir de:

```
<audio controls id="audio" src="data:audio/mpeg;base64,T2dnUwACAAAAAAAAAAA+HAAAAAAAAGyawCEBQGZpc2h"></audio>
```

En este caso el string `base64` es un ejemplo quizá demasiado corto pero ya entienden a lo que me refiero.

He probado con el:

```
audio.duration;
```

Pero supongo que por ser base64 y no un fichero de audio me devuelve `NaN` (not a number), en cambio el elemento mostrado en pantalla sí conoce su duración antes de empezar a reproducirse.

¿Habría alguna manera de obtener la duración de la cadena `base64`?

Comment: en que evento recuperas el audio.duration? porque quizas lo haces en un momento cuando un no se renderizo completo el html. Deberias hacerlo en el onload

Comment: intente definir el tag audio, en jsfiddle pero no reconoce el base64, estas seguro que ese base64 es valido ? si pones este en un bloque de codigo en stackoverflow se renderiza correctamente ?

Comment: https://iandevlin.com/html5/data-uri/audio.php

Comment: el audio esta extraído de aquí, tambien he probado de obtener la duration cuando toda la metadata este cargada pero da NaN igualmente

Comment: a que metadata te refieres ? yo solo apuntaba a conocer en que evento html usaste, fue en el onload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realice la siguiente prueba

https://jsfiddle.net/529u2yr6/

```
var audio1 = document.getElementById("audio1");

audio1.onloadeddata = function() {
    alert(audio1.duration);
};
```

Y puedo obtener la duracion del audio, para verla recuerda realizar un F5 de la página ya que este se visualiza cuando re recarga el audio por completo

Como comente debes acceer a este dato en el evento adecuado que permita asegurar que el audio o video haya sido cargado completamente

Nota: tuve que poner el ejemplo en jsfiddler porque el tamaño del audio superaba lo permitido por stackoverflow